# How can i define custom route and controller in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I have some custom field on Laravel nova with my own server rendered ui. I made this field by using  https://github.com/JoshMoreno/nova-html-field

[image]

but i need this custom field with a button (will add this button as directly to blade view as HTML). So i need to add a route i will be able run from nova (when admin press this button) and some handler to catch it... Maybe some one would know how can i achieve this?